# Count how often a category occurs on a single day

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following data frame:

```
> dput(head(testFrame, 10))
structure(list(`df$data.founded_at` = structure(c(15492, 15639, 
15065, 15340, 15257, 13514, 14610, 14975, 15340, 11323), class = "Date")), .Names = "df$data.founded_at", row.names = c("Entertainment", 
"Publishing", "Electronics", "Software", "Software.1", "Curated Web", 
"Software.2", "Analytics", "E-Commerce", "E-Commerce.1"), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to count for each day how often the same category occurs and add the value to a new column. For example.: Lets take the 1.1.2000, then if the category `Software` occurs in the dataset 5 times on the 1.1.2000 then there should be added 5 to the last column.

Here is another example visualized in a table:

```
date            category         freq
1.1.2011        E-Commerce       2
3.3.2013        Software         2
1.1.2011        E-Commerce       2
2.5.2014        Analytics        1
2.5.2014        Search           1
3.3.2013        Software         2
```

Any recommendations how to implement that?

Thx in advance for your inpu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `data.table` (the data you provided didn't have any duplicates so I've used the data from your desired output without the `freq` column)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(testFrame)[, freq := .N, by = list(date, category)]
testFrame
#        date   category freq
# 1: 1.1.2011 E-Commerce    2
# 2: 3.3.2013   Software    2
# 3: 1.1.2011 E-Commerce    2
# 4: 2.5.2014  Analytics    1
# 5: 2.5.2014     Search    1
# 6: 3.3.2013   Software    2
```

---

You can also do it with base R using the very efficient `transform` and `ave` functions

```
transform(testFrame, freq = ave(seq_len(nrow(testFrame)), list(date, category), FUN = length))

#       date   category freq
# 1 1.1.2011 E-Commerce    2
# 2 3.3.2013   Software    2
# 3 1.1.2011 E-Commerce    2
# 4 2.5.2014  Analytics    1
# 5 2.5.2014     Search    1
# 6 3.3.2013   Software    2
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Its weired that there is `Software, Software.1 etc.`, because when doing `VIEW(testFrame)` I cannot see that.

Comment: The problem isn't just with `Software, Software.1` in your data, the problem is that all the dates are unique